# Graphs with $\operatorname{diam}(G)=2\operatorname{rad}(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

When is the diameter of a graph equal to twice of radius? I am currently studying graph theory and have faced many questions related to graphs with the mentioned property. Is there any general class of graphs which follow this property?

I know path graphs with odd vertices are such graphs, but is there a more general graph?

Comment: A tree has this property if and only if it has a center vertex. By a center vertex, I mean, consider iteratively removing leaves, i.e. at step one, remove all leaves, then at step 2 repeat. In a tree, you'll either be left with an edge or with a vertex. If you're left with a vertex, then that's called the center vertex of the tree. You can quickly check that a center vertex of a tree is exactly the realizer that $diam(G)=2rad(G)$.

Comment: Generally these sorts of extremal questions can get pretty thorny and so are considered pretty specialized; you might get more attention from experts if you ask at MathOverflow.

Comment: (e.g. this property was shown [for interval graphs with even diameter](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf0d/504414d3d79e689ae7d52e3d9ab96413a49a.pdf)— fairly recently, and with quite a bit of effort.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by munchhausen and me, there exist at least two classes of graphs with the "$d=2r$ property", generalizing your example of a path with an odd number of vertices:

- A tree has this property if and only if it has a center vertex.
- An interval graph has this property if and only if its diameter is even.

The intersection of these two classes is quite a small proportion of either, which suggests that the collection of graphs with the $d=2r$ property may be (otherwise) quite heterogeneous.

Comment: Thanks for the paper by the way. It's nice!